# 301 redirect in the htaccess file issues

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

This is driving me crazy, can anybody tell me why this 301 redirect does not work. I just get a 404 error with the old /about page. Here is the code for info:

```
{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END WP Rocket

RewriteEngine on
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /about https://scottcarneyphotography.com/about
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: The directives you've posted are not complete - the first few look like they have been cropped? What redirect are you trying to do exactly? I can see one redirect from `/about` to `/about` - which obviously doesn't make a whole lot of sense?! Is that on a different domain or the same domain? You have other errors (directives in the wrong order) and other seemingly superfluous directives?

Comment: the redirect is from one domain where the htaccess file is located. /about then it is redirecting to the new domain which is https://www.scottcarneyphotography.com/about so the bit I added is the following. Redirect 301 /about https://www.scottcarneyphotography/about

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /about https://scottcarneyphotography.com/about
> ```

The `Redirect` directive belongs to mod_alias and consequently runs after the existing mod_rewrite directives in your config file, this is possibly resulting in a conflict.

You should move this *redirect* to the *top* of your `.htaccess` file and convert it to mod_rewrite instead. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^about$ https://scottcarneyphotography.com/about [R=301,L]
```

---

However, there are other potential issues with your `.htaccess` file...

> ```
> {ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" -f
> RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
> </IfModule>
> # END WP Rocket
> ```

I guess you're not showing your complete config file, however, these directives are literally chopped in half - so they don't look valid. There may also be directives earlier in the file that may conflict with your redirect.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

These directives (at the end of the `.htaccess` file, after the WordPress front-controller) are in the wrong place and consequently will not work as intended (to redirect all traffic to HTTPS). They should be near the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller.

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> ```

There's no need for spurious/multiple `RewriteEngine` directives strewn, seemingly arbitrarily, throughout the config file. You only *need* one of these. (Keep the one inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block.)

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> :
> </IfModule>
> # END WordPress
> ```

You should avoid manually editing the directives between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers. This is maintained by WordPress, so could be overwritten by WordPress in future updates (unless you have explicitly blocked WP from doing this).

Answer (score 1):

Check please if add to top `.htaccess` file (before WP Rocket rewrites) this 301 redirect work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about\/$ https://scottcarneyphotography.com/about/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Wordpress default add `/` to end of URL address, maybe request is `/about/` not `/about`.